# Correct preposition for dual citizenship

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is preferred:

> 1. He is a dual citizen of the US and Canada.

or

> 2. He is a dual citizen in the US and Canada.

Comment: The same as for single citizenship. It is *a citizen **of** the world*, not *a citizen in the world*.

Comment: "Al-Huthaili is a dual citizen **of** the U.S. and Saudi Arabia and the two countries are not bound by a bilateral extradition treaty. " (emphasis mine).  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dual-citizen

Answer (score 2):

1. He is a dual citizen of the US and Canada.